# Compute standard-error/deviation for an aggregated/ fractional metric

Tags: r, confidence-interval, data-visualization, inference, uncertainty

I have a dataset, where I want to visualize an aggregated efficiency over time (t), while also showing the variation/ uncertainty in the data.

The target metric is computed as the fraction of the output (return) for some kind of input. The input and output is already aggregated data, so the number of observations (n_obs) are already present in the data.

It's obvious to me, that more observations and possibly also more input would decrease the uncertainty for the output_per_input-metric. But somehow I'm not sure how to arrive at a reasonable statistic for the variation.

What options do I have (to put meaningful error bars into the plot below) ?
Input and Output are actually positively correlated (so not entirely independent, r ~ 0.3 or so)

```r
set.seed(123)

library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(t = 1:10,
               output = rnorm(10, mean = 5, sd = 3),
               input = sample(1:100, 10),
               n_obs = sample(2:8, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(output_per_input = output / input)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(t, output_per_input, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = n_obs, size = input)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>